# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: net.classify is not a function

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have read several answers that related to this kind of question/problem and nothing works.
I have javascript for loading and predict the tensorflow model.

```
let net;

async function app() {
  console.log('Loading model...');

  net = await tf.loadLayersModel('path/to/model.json');
  console.log('Successfully loaded model');

  const imgEl = document.getElementById('img');
  const result = await net.classify(imgEl);
  console.log(result);
}

app();
```

and resulting this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: net.classify is not a function
```

is there any way to overcome this situation?

Comment: Looks like `classify` isn't a method on tensorflow models: https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#class:LayersModel

Comment: I use classify method when using mobilenet model with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is convert it into a tensor and change the "classify" method into the "predict" method

```
async function app() {
  console.log('Loading Model...');

  const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('path/to/model.json');
  console.log('Successfully loaded model');

  const imgEl = document.getElementById('img');
  let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgEl)
    .resizeNearestNeighbor([299, 299])
    .toFloat()
    .expandDims();

  let predictions = await model.predict(tensor).data();
  console.log(predictions)
}
app();
```